# Python int(90.0) = 89 error

Tags: python, int

This is a glitch in a larger program I wrote that I can't figure out. I'm using Python 2.7.

```
n = 0.5
while n < 2:
    print(int(n * 100))
    n += 0.1
```

The output for 90, 100, and 110 are off by 1.
Truncated output:
50,
60,
70,
80,
89,
99,
109,
120,
130,
140,
...

This doesn't happen when I a) start with n = 0.8, b) print the floating point numbers directly, or c) don't increment n using a loop as with:

```
n = 0.9
print(int(n * 100))
```

I know there are many work arounds to this, but I'm still curious as to why this might be occurring. It was part of a file naming function for ordering output files of raw data. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to floating point. Also, `range(50,200,10)` would suit your purposes better.

Comment: I forgot about range(), thanks. The iteration occurs elsewhere in the program from the int() conversion. This was just simplest code I could write to duplicate the problem. I guess I could have made it simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic is inexact.  There are many, many resources out there that will explain why - here's one general starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error

And a Python-specific tutorial:
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

If you need exact representations of decimal numbers, use the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) built in library.  Usually you don't, but it's there if you need it.

Comment: The `decimal` library worked.
As for floating point, I guess I was assuming too much about what value was printed to screen. Another workaround (using my assumptions about what was printed to screen) was:
`print(int(float(str(n * 100))))`
It's ugly, but worked.